# Join line to multiple points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I took some ASCII files and created points with attributes. I am trying to join the line features to these but a simple join function will only take the one that is closest. Is there a way to perhaps duplicate a line feature if there are two points that correspond to it? I am trying to accomplish this on ArcGIS.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you want the [Spatial Join tool.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) The difference between this and just right-clicking and joining your layer is that there is an option to select the Join Operation.

If you change this to Join-One-To-Many your line feature will be repeated for every point it intersects:

> JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY —If multiple join features are found that have the
>   same spatial relationship with a single target feature, the output
>   feature class will contain multiple copies (records) of the target
>   feature.

[image: Spatial Join]

In addition to this the tool provides more methods of how the Match is carried out, which may also be useful.